# How to test this functional component

Tags: reactjs, karma-mocha

I need the help with testing this component using [expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) library with karma and mocha.

```
import React from 'react';

import {Clock} from 'Clock';
import {CountdownForm} from "CountdownForm";
import {Controls} from "Controls";

export class Countdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      countdownStatus: 'stopped'
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.countdownStatus !== this.state.countdownStatus) {
      switch (this.state.countdownStatus) {
        case 'started':
          this.timerID = setInterval(
            this.tick,
          1000
          );
         break;
        case 'stopped':
          console.log('stopped fireeed');
          this.setState({count: 0});
        case 'paused':
          console.log('paused fireeed');
          clearInterval(this.timerID)
          this.timerID = undefined;
          break;

      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID)
    this.timerID = undefined;
  }


  handleSetCountdown =  (seconds) => {
    this.setState({
      count: seconds,
      countdownStatus: 'started'
    });

  }

  tick = () => {
    console.log('tick fireeeed');
    let newMoment = this.state.count - 1;
    let newState = 'started'
    if(newMoment === 0) {
      newState = 'stopped'
    }
    this.setState(() => {
        return {
          count: newMoment >= 0 ? newMoment : 0,
          countdownStatus: newState
        }
    })
  }

  handleStatusChange = (newStatus) => {
    this.setState({
      countdownStatus: newStatus,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const renderControlArea = () => {
      if(this.state.countdownStatus !== 'stopped') {
        return <Controls countdownStatus={this.state.countdownStatus} onStatusChange={this.handleStatusChange}/>
      } else {
        return <CountdownForm onSetCountdown={this.handleSetCountdown}/>
      }
    }
    const count = this.state.count
    return (
      <div>
        <Clock totalSeconds={count}/>
        {renderControlArea()}
        {/* <CountdownForm onSetCountdown={this.handleSetCountdown}/> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const Controls = (props) => {
  const  renderStartStopButton = (countdownStatus) => {
    if(countdownStatus === 'started') {
      return <button className="button secondary" onClick={() => props.onStatusChange('paused')}>Pause</button>
    }
    else if (countdownStatus === 'paused'){
      return <button className="button primary" onClick={() => props.onStatusChange('started')}>Start</button>
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="controls">
      {renderStartStopButton(props.countdownStatus)}
      <button className="button alert hollow" onClick={() => props.onStatusChange('stopped')}>Clear</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export {Controls}
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work, it seems like I should test if the function is called when countdownStatus is passed. Here is the error [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g8p3.png):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import expect from 'expect';
import $ from 'jQuery';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

import { Controls } from "Controls"

describe('Controls', () => {
  it('should exist', () => {
    expect(Controls).toExist()
  });

  describe('render', () => {
    it('should render pause button when started', () => {
      var controls = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Controls countdownStatus={'started'}/>);
      var $el = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(controls));
      var $PauseBtn = $el.find('button:contains(Pause)');

      expect($PauseBtn.length).toBe(1);
    });

    it('should render start button when paused', () => {
      var controls = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Controls countdownStatus={'paused'}/>);
      var $el = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(controls));
      var $StartBtn = $el.find('button:contains(Start)');

      expect($StartBtn.length).toBe(1);
    });

  });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was that I couldn't  node into the document before it got returned from the Control function. I figured it out, just in case someone is dealing with the similar issue keep in mind you are testing function not Class here is the code that fixes problem

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import expect from 'expect';
import $ from 'jQuery';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

import { Controls } from "Controls"

describe('Controls', () => {
  it('should exist', () => {
    expect(Controls).toExist()
  });

  describe('render', () => {
    it('should render pause button when started', () => {
      var controls = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(Controls({countdownStatus:'started'}));
      var $el = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(controls));
      var $PauseBtn = $el.find('button:contains(Pause)');

      expect($PauseBtn.length).toBe(1);
    });

    it('should render start button when paused', () => {
      var controls = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(Controls({countdownStatus:'paused'}));
      var $el = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(controls));
      var $StartBtn = $el.find('button:contains(Start)');

      expect($StartBtn.length).toBe(1);
    });

  });

})
```